# Solr relational database

Tags: database, solr

Can solr be used as a relational database?

I am building a product database using Solr, but i am also trying to add competitor products within the same database, so when one item comes up the equivalent of other entries also show up

Answer (score 1):

No, Solr should not be used as a relational database.

That does not mean that what you want isn't a good fit for Solr, just that it main usefulness lies outside of what relational databases are good at.

You can use regular search, "MoreLikeThis" or similar functionality (such as graphs or analytics from the streaming expressions support) to find similar or identical products.